# My KML maps went blank after I pushed a minor update to one of them

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm experiencing a very strange problem. As of yesterday the 36 KML maps I have posted to my website were appearing just fine. (It's one U.S. map showing train stations and 35 state maps.) Then I amended the coding of my main map to add one new icon to the 1,639 icons I already had on the map, and the map went blank. I restored the previous version and now that version was blank. All the other maps for individual states, none of which had been touched, have now also gone blank.

Does anyone have troubleshooting advice? What could I have done to one file that caused all 36 files to go blank?

My main map is here:
http://www.startsandfits.com/RailMaps/USRailMap.html

My individual state maps are here:
http://www.startsandfits.com/

Comment: I see a javascript error on your main map `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined`

Comment: Looks like [your KML isn't valid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.startsandfits.com%2FRailMaps%2FNewUSRailStations.kml)

Comment: OK, many thanks geocodezip. I am starting to think that my entire coding, involving a fake KML gadget hosted on my website, is completely wrong, and that it was pretty much a miracle that it was working at all.  I think I am going to basically start from scratch.